# Calculation Group slows down as the number of Calculation Items in the group increases

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

We are building a report that uses a Calculation Group that allows our users to select the measures they see in a table. But regardless of how many metrics the user chooses, the table is slow to load. And the more Calculation Items we add to the Calculation Group, the slower the table becomes. It seems that the Calculation Groups queries all the Calculation Items in the group, even the Calculation Items the user didn't select.

Can anyone give any insights on why this is happening, or any advice on how to optimize a large Calculation Group?

Comment: I've had a similar experience: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805513/force-dax-switch-function-to-use-strict-lazy-short-circuit-evaluation